# In how many ways can one arrange the letters of the word 'EDUCATION' such that order of vowels don't change?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Basically it means that the vowels must come in the order - E, U, A, I, O and can be place anywhere in the word.
I tried to do it by assuming that each of the vowels can come in five different spots. But I didn't get anywhere...

Comment: At a first thought $5! \cdot {9 \choose 4} $.

Comment: Yeah even i thought of that but it isn't promising

Answer (score 1):

Don't place vowels - think of them as already "placed" and place *consonants* instead. 'D' can be placed in any of 6 positions: `.E.U.A.I.O.`. After that, 'C' has 7 placements and so on. Since all consonants are different, any two different sequential placements will produce different "ways to arrange letters" and any way to arrange letters corresponds to some such placement.

Thus the answer is $6*7*8*9 = \frac{9!}{5!} = 3024$.

Comment: No, but we need to make sure that the order of just the vowels remain same 9P4 cannot be used.

Comment: @bull I'm not sure I understand your objection. The placement described clearly leaves vowels in the same (e-u-a-i-o) order. Or do you mean that the order of consonants *must* change? That was not obvoius from the question.